# Help Solving Equation From A Paper

Tags: problem-solving

In the paper, entitled:

> A Closed Form Solution for the Pull-in Voltage of the Micro Bridge

(Link to PDF: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d31/33707b1243f6b4e3344c4fa19b831b010b8b.pdf)

... the following equation appears:

[image]

I really don't know how to solve this for $\eta_{PI}$, even if all constants are known... do you have any idea ?

EDIT: 
In LateX:

$\eta_{ P I } = \frac{\int_{ 0 } ^ { L } \left[ \frac { b \phi } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 2 } } + \frac { 0.265 b ^ { 0.25 } \phi } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 1.25 } } + \frac { 0.53 h ^ { 0.5 } \phi } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 1.5 } } \right] dx}{\int _ { 0 } ^ { L } \left[ \frac { 2 b \phi ^ { 2 } } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 3 } } + \frac { 0.33125 b ^ { 0.25 } \phi ^ { 2 } } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 225 } } + \frac { 0.795 h ^ { 0.5 } \phi ^ { 2 } } { \left( g - \eta _ { P I } \phi \right) ^ { 25 } } \right] d x}$

A typical $\phi (x) =a \sin (x)+b \cos (x)+c \sinh (x)+d \cosh (x)$

**Update:**
Because this seems to be a very difficult task to solve analytically, I have also posted a question on Mathematica SE to see if it can be solved numerically. If you are interested in getting the Mathematica code to test it, please have a look here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183262/how-to-solve-this-equation-numerically-or-analytically?

Comment: I don't think that it is the intention of the article to obtain ${\eta}_{PI}$ analytically. In the article https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4135062 by the same authors, it is under the header The Approximate Analytical Solution. So that expression is as far as you're going to get.

Comment: @StijnDietz Thanks for the article. Okay, I see. But they don't write how they calculate it. They simply state the results. How could it be done numerically ? btw: Naming it "A Closed Form Solution" without solution... oh well.

Comment: $\phi(x)$ is term subject to integration (in the formula written as $\phi$ for clarity) and that term is present in the numerators and denominators across both integrals. Unfortunately, I do not know how this would be done numerically.